# Extract string from html title with wget and sed

Tags: linux, sed, wget

I have an html page response like:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>ThisIsFile.zip - Company</title>
...
```

I tried to output to a file the `ThisIsFile.zip` name only

```
wget --trust-server-names 'https://blablabla' | sed -E -i 's/<title>(.*) - Company<\/title>/\1/g' > /my/location.txt
```

But is shown as empty ...I expected that `\1` should be `ThisIsFile.zip`

Comment: Ask yourself what `-O` does here.

Comment: Save content of webpage in that text file

Comment: Right. So sed does not even get any input. You would have to run sed on the file, or pipe the output of wget to sed directly.

Comment: I changed the command, still not get my expected string.

Comment: old wisdom about parsing html with regex:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/501765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problems:

1. `-O /downloads/tmp/cd.txt` sends output to a file, not to stdout. Without `-O` option `wget` will still download one or more files. Use `-O -` to send to stdout.
2. You need to filter out other lines, therefore `grep '<title>'` or similar command should precede `sed`.
3. Spaces preceding `<title>` will stay. Adjust `sed` or use `grep -o`. There are few solutions.

```
wget --trust-server-names 'https://blablabla' -O - \
| grep -o '<title>.*</title>' \
| sed -E 's/<title>(.*) - Company<\/title>/\1/'
```

Additionally you may or may not want `wget --quiet …`.

Comment: `sed` can be avoided if using Gnu grep (look-behind/look-ahead in PCREs): `grep -Po '(?<=<title>).+(?= -)'`